# Lab 30V 10A PSU - no current in CC mode when shorted

Tags: power-supply

I have problem with my PSU, which is similar costruction to Mastech HY3010 (exactly this is MCP lab electronics M10-SP-3010E)
When I short the output, no matter what I set on potentiometers, there's no current at the output. It goes into CC mode, but stays at 0 amps. When I connect some higher resistance it works fine, until the voltage drops somewhere below 0,8V. Then no matter how I manipulate the gauges it stays at 0A. When i disconnect the load, and set higher current it works fine.[image: schematic] What is even more interesting - when I touch D11 diode with my finger ,when output is shorted, something is happening at the output, the current shows up for a while. What can cause that problem?

Edit:
I've already chcecked all wires, all soldering points, and everything is fine. Also done some measurements on U2 and U3 op-amps and checked all supply voltages. Still cannot find any problem :/
I don't understand why LED1 an LED2 are connected between op-amps outputs, and transistor base. Can somebody explain me that circuit?

Comment: This unit almost certainly has short circuit protection.  It shuts down the output when it detects a short circuit condition.  I have to ask, why are you shorting the output?  Nothing good can come of that.

Comment: @jwh20 On my lab supply, this is the procedure for setting the current limit...

Comment: I have another lab power supply and there's nothing like this. I short terminals to set maximum current (in CC mode). Every power supply which I've been using wasn't behaving like this.

Comment: CC mode or current limiting, are independent of short circuit protections, despite having similar behaviour. the addition of short protection is because in CC mode, the controller usually takes some cycles to regulate the output so the current stays in range, but these few cycles could be intolerable for other parts connected.

Comment: Yeah, but this power supply when shorted should go into CC mode and put current (set by the dials) at the output.